# error: implicit declaration of function ‘sys_kill’

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I've created a system call to return a tag variable (that I added in the kernel) of a specific process.
When I make I get *error: implicit declaration of function ‘sys_kill’*.  Does anyone know what might be causing this or if there are any alternative functions I can use to see if a process is running to return the tag?

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>    
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/signal.h>
#include "header.h"

asmlinkage int sys_get_thing(int pid){  //gets the process ID
  struct task_struct *p;                   //pointer to the struct
  p = find_task_by_vpid(pid);       //p = process found by PID

  if(sys_kill(p->pid, 0) == 0){ //syskill sends a 0 signal to all processes matching passed PID - checks if running
    return p->tag;  //the 0 signal found has the tag we are looking for
  }
  else{
    return -1;          //if nothing is found return -1
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems `sys_kill` cannot be found in the prototypes. Is it `sys_kill` or `syskill`?

Comment: I believe it's sys_kill, to be sure, I tried syskill just now and got the same error.

Comment: The name is just `kill`. See https://linux.die.net/man/3/kill

Comment: I tried that too and got the same error, also I believe kill is for userspace, and I am  working in kernel space.

Comment: There is no `sys_kill` in the documentation. Check your .h files!

Comment: I used grep and found this: include/linux/syscalls.h:633:asmlinkage long sys_kill(pid_t pid, int sig);

Comment: You can compile to produce only the pre-processor output (I don't know the option for your compiler; check the documentation). Check if this prototype is in this output. If not, then the symbol is excluded (by a conditional compilation, `#define`) from the output. Check the define's around it. This is all the help I can give. Sometimes it is a puzzle...

Comment: I don't think you're typically meant to call the `sys_*` entry points from within the kernel.  For one thing, they tend to expect pointers to userspace memory instead of kernel space.  There is usually some other "internal use" function that does what you want, so I would suggest looking for that.  Seeing what `sys_kill` calls could be a good start.  This other function is likely to be declared in some appropriate kernel header that you could include, but the omission of `sys_kill` is probably intentional.

Comment: But if the process doesn't exist, surely your `find_task_by_vpid` would have failed?  So what is `kill(pid,0)` going to accomplish anyway?  Why not just check whether `p` is non-NULL (which you should do anyway) and if so simply return `p->tag`?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing and it worked out @NateEldredge

Answer (score 0):

The call in the kernel is `kill_something_info` as implemented in signal.c.  An exmple syscall definition is here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.14/source/kernel/signal.c#L2860

Comment: That's a very descriptive name, although `kill_something_or_other` would've been better :P

Comment: `kill_something_info` is declared `static` so it can't be called from other source files.  If there is a `kill` function meant to be called from generic places in the kernel, this is not it.  My guess would be `kill_proc_info` but I am not certain.

Answer (score 0):

`sys_kill` does not exist for architectures using syscall wrappers (those architectures that define `CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER`). Even if it does exist, the advice in "include/linux/syscalls.h" should be observed:

```
 * Please note that these prototypes here are only provided for information
 * purposes, for static analysis, and for linking from the syscall table.
 * These functions should not be called elsewhere from kernel code.
```

Also, the `asmlinkage int sys_get_tag(int pid)` function definition will be ineffective on those architectures that use syscall wrapping. In order to work on all architectures, , and since it has one parameter, it should be written as `SYSCALL_DEFINE1(get_tag, int, pid)`.

There is no need to send a signal to a task from kernel space to determine whether it exists. Any task found exists, although a found task might be marked as dead and perhaps such tasks should be ignored by OP's system call. This can be done by checking `p->state & TASK_DEAD`.

Calls to `find_task_by_vpid` should be protected by `rcu_read_lock()` and unless the task structure's reference is incremented by `get_task_struct(task)` before the matching `rcu_read_unlock()`, the task structure found is no longer valid.  There is a `find_get_task_by_vpid` function that combines the effect of `find_task_by_vpid` and `get_task_struct` with proper RCU locking.

Rather than returning `-1`, the syscall should return an appropriate negated `errno` value. This will cause the userspace systecall to return `-1` and set the `errno` variable. If the process cannot be found, an appropriate `errno` value is `ESRCH`, so the kernel implementation of the syscall should return `-ESRCH` if the process is not found.

Here are two possible implementations of the syscall. The first uses RCU locking directly:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(get_tag, int, pid)
{
    struct task_struct *p; // pointer to the struct
    int rc = -ESRCH;       // default return value when not found

    rcu_read_lock();
    p = find_task_by_vpid(pid);       // p = process found by PID
    if (p && !(p->state & TASK_DEAD)) // process exists and is not dead
        rc = p->tag;                  // the tag we are looking for
    rcu_read_unlock();

    return rc;
}
```

The second uses `find_get_task_vpid` and `put_task_struct` instead of explicit RCU locking (the RCU locking and unlocking is done within the call to `find_get_task_vpid`):

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(get_tag, int, pid)
{
    struct task_struct *p; // pointer to the struct
    int rc = -ESRCH;       // default return value when not found

    p = find_get_task_by_vpid(pid);   // p = process found by PID
    if (p) {                          // process exists ...
        if (!(p->state & TASK_DEAD))  // ... and is not dead
            rc = p->tag;              // the tag we are looking for
        put_task_struct(p);
    }

    return rc;
}
```